# Range values to be calculated in PHP Loop

Tags: php

I need to calculate if avg is > 7.75 means Heavy else No.

What the concern is that.

Need to calculate that from $x to $y range of all numbers comes int.

But i was able to get one Avg only not sure what to do to get all numbers Average values and store in Array comes in that range.

```
    function heavyDecC ($x,$y)
{

    for($i=$x;$i<=$y;$i++)
    {
        $numb = $i;
        $numleng = strlen((string)$i);
        $int = 0;
        for($j=0;$j<$numleng;$j++)
        {

            $int = $int + ($numb % 10);
            $numb = (int)$numb / 10;
        }
        $avg = 0.00;
        $avg = round($int/$numleng,2);
        if($avg>7)
        {
            $isHeavy = "Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            $isHeavy = "No";
        }

        return $result[] = array($i,$avg,$isHeavy);
    }
}
```

Comment: All numbers average values? What does that mean? What do you want the results to look like?

Comment: like for paramer 1 enter : 9872 and parameter2 = 9884 result need like this http://prntscr.com/bli0gp

Comment: Your `return` is inside the for loop, so you are not going to loop thru anymore than the first time. EDIT: after looking at the code closer and your description, I think this is it. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: not works still return one result ?

Comment: Hy, did u check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a simple solution**

```
<?php

$results = heavyDecC(2685, 5875);

// Display results like this
foreach ($results as $id){
        echo "--------------------------<br/>";
        foreach($id as $key => $val){
            echo $key . " - " . $val . "<br />";
        }
    }

function heavyDecC ($x,$y) {

    for($i=$x; $i<=$y; $i++){
        $num = $x;
        $isHeavy = "No";
        $num_length = strlen((string)$num);
        $array  = array_map('intval', str_split($num));
        $sum = array_sum($array);
        $average = ($sum / $num_length);

            if($average > 7){
                $isHeavy = "Yes";
            }else {
                $isHeavy = "No";
            }

        $newdata =  array (
              'Number' => $num,
              'average' => $average,
              'is_heavy' => $isHeavy
            );

        $md_array[$i]= $newdata;
        $x++;

    }

return $md_array;
}

?>
```

**Results like this**

```
--------------------------
Number - 2991
average - 5.25
is_heavy - No
--------------------------
Number - 2992
average - 5.5
is_heavy - No
--------------------------
Number - 2993
average - 5.75
is_heavy - No
--------------------------
Number - 2994
average - 6
is_heavy - No
--------------------------
Number - 2995
average - 6.25
is_heavy - No
--------------------------
Number - 2996
average - 6.5
is_heavy - No
--------------------------
Number - 2997
average - 6.75
is_heavy - No
--------------------------
Number - 2998
average - 7
is_heavy - No
--------------------------
Number - 2999
average - 7.25
is_heavy - Yes
--------------------------
```

Comment: And Thanks for Rest of all mates :)

Answer (score 0):

Move your `return` outside of the `for` loop, like this:

```
 function heavyDecC ($x,$y)
{
    $result = array();
    for($i=$x;$i<=$y;$i++)
    {
        $numb = $i;
        $numleng = strlen((string)$i);
        $int = 0;
        for($j=0;$j<$numleng;$j++)
        {

            $int = $int + ($numb % 10);
            $numb = (int)$numb / 10;
        }
        $avg = 0.00;
        $avg = round($int/$numleng,2);
        if($avg>7)
        {
            $isHeavy = "Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            $isHeavy = "No";
        }

        $result[] = array($i,$avg,$isHeavy);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I just edited to make it work. You need to instantiate the `$result` array before the loop, then push the results into the array each time thru the loop, then you need to return the `$result` array.

Answer (score 0):

You have return value in every loop so it will only get last index values ! So you need to return outside of the loop ....

```
   function heavyDecC ($x,$y)
{
    $result = array();
    for($i=$x;$i<=$y;$i++)
    {
        $numb = $i;
        $numleng = strlen((string)$i);
        $int = 0;
        for($j=0;$j<$numleng;$j++)
        {

            $int = $int + ($numb % 10);
            $numb = (int)$numb / 10;
        }
        $avg = 0.00;
        $avg = round($int/$numleng,2);
        if($avg>7)
        {
            $isHeavy = "Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            $isHeavy = "No";
        }

        $result[] = array($i,$avg,$isHeavy);
    }
    return $result; // return here outside of loop
}
```